# How to update PHP in Cent OS 6.8?

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, centos7

I try to update PHP 5.5 to up using command:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

> Retrieving
>   https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
>   warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.4xrPQL: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key
>   ID 352c64e5: NOKEY error: Failed dependencies:    epel-release = 6 is
>   needed by (installed) remi-release-6.8-1.el6.remi.noarch  epel-release
>   = 6 is needed by (installed) ius-release-1.0-14.ius.centos6.noarch

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should epel for CentOS 6 not 7:

```
sudo yum install php-common    
sudo rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
sudo yum install php70w php70w-opcache
sudo yum install php70w-fpm php70w-opcache
sudo yum install yum-plugin-replace
sudo yum replace php-common --replace-with=php70w-common
sudo yum install php70w-opcache

# remove old php-cli
sudo yum remove php-cli
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/php
sudo yum -y install php70w-cli
```

For more informations check this [link](https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/)

Comment: I get message: `Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
 package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed
[root@qobustan bin]# 
`

Comment: All commands return me Nothing to do and last command gives:  1sudo yum replace php-common --replace-with=php70w-common
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Replacing packages takes time, please be patient...
Error: Package 'php-common' is not installed.`

Comment: you got error int the last command because php-common is not installed before `yum install php-common` - answer updated

Comment: you should install `php70w-cli`

Comment: I have this package: `Package php70w-cli-7.0.12-1.w6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
`

Comment: These commands now work, but `php -v` gives me still previous version php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127313/discussion-between-developer-and-misterpi).

Comment: What is the provider of the current version of PHP (remi ? IUS ? webtatic ? as it seems better to keep same provider) ?   rpm -qf $(which php)