# upgrading php 5.6.3 to 5.6.4 or higher (branch 5.6)

Tags: php, centos7

I have a Centos 7, with a php 5.6.3 installed on it.

```
php -v
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2017 07:08:58)
```

Now I want to install an open source project that requires minimum php version 5.6.4.

```
(*) PHP 5.6.0 - 5.6.3 are not compatible caused by a session bug
```

How can I do the upgrade?
I tried many howto's found with google, but none of them work. For example:
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=52586
Of course I have the latest (I think) repos:

> package webtatic-release-7-3.noarch is already installed
>
> package epel-release-7-9.noarch already installed and latest version

When I run

```
yum update php
```

I get:

```
...
Package(s) php available, but not installed.
No packages marked for update
```

or:

```
yum -y upgrade php*
```

I get:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.hostingfuze.net
 * extras: centos.mirrors.telekom.ro
 * ius: ftp.astral.ro
 * remi-safe: mirrors.neterra.net
 * updates: centos.mirrors.telekom.ro
No packages marked for update
```

So basically my question is: **how can I install the PHP 5.6.4 or higher on my system that already has PHP 5.6.3**

Comment: 5.6.30 is newer than 5.6.4 (`30 > 4`) - it's the newest version of the 5.6 branch. Version 5.6.4 was released at the end of 2014.

Comment: Thanks. I did not see it that way. Good to know. Make your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.30), 5.6.30 **is** (as of today) the newest version of the 5.6 branch, 5.6.4 came out December 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yum install -y http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/7/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-14.ius.centos7.noarch.rpm
yum -y update
yum -y install php70u php70u-pdo php70u-mysqlnd php70u-opcache php70u-xml php70u-mcrypt php70u-gd php70u-devel php70u-mysql php70u-intl php70u-mbstring php70u-bcmath php70u-json php70u-iconv
```

or check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40406823/7804966

Comment: Sorry I must specify in the question that I want to stick with the 5.6 branch not go to the 7 branch yet