# Laravel 5.4 PHP requirements (5.6.30 vs 5.6.40)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, version, laravel-5.4

I'd like to use Laravel 5.4 on my production server but the latest PHP 5.6 version available is 5.6.30 (as my local XAMPP installation as well), while the requirements for Laravel 5.4 are php >= 5.6.40 as for https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel

Now, I've successfully installed Laravel 5.4 on the server in a subdirectory via SSH and the home page is showing the Laravel logo. Is there some problems I could encounter using this version of PHP down the road? If so, is there any polyfill or adjustment to be made in order to use Laravel 5.4 on PHP 5.6.30 instead of PHP 5.6.40? Thanks

Comment: That's `5.6.4`, `4 < 30`, `PHP 5.6.4` came out December 2014.

Comment: Oh, I see! I automatically assumed 4 was 40 and 30 was older for some reason. I can't believe how dumb I was. Many thanks to you @ccKep

Comment: You're not the first one to make that mistake, see [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174053/upgrading-php-5-6-3-to-5-6-4-or-higher-branch-5-6#comment73422165_43174053) (I can't vote for duplicate since that OP didn't accept an answer...)

Answer (score 6):

Laravel require php 5.6.4 as you can see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation#server-requirements) 
and XAMPP is 5.6.30 - This version is NEWER than 5.6.4 ( see all php versions [here](https://secure.php.net/releases/) )
So no problems are expected becase you are using newer version than required by Laravel.

Comment: Thanks. There's a lot of confusion as many people (like me until 10 minutes ago) believed PHP 5.6.4 > PHP 5.6.30 as there was an implicit yet wrong conversion of 4 to 40 so > 30. Hopefully this thread will help avoiding confusion as the last PHP 5 version will likely be 5.6.30 if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel (project name) 5.4.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7ya6.png)

that will install the latest version of laravel supported by php 5.6
see in the attachment above

```
  composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel (project name) 5.4.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.4 is compatible with PHP 7.x. Please check the following article.
https://murze.be/2016/01/why-we-are-requiring-php-7-for-our-new-packages/